# Webrtc getStat() SSRC stat Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session, statistics, webrtc

I am trying to access the ssrc stat using the getStat() method from the webrtc API but am not able to get it.

Here is my implementation:

```
var selector  = pc.getRemoteStreams()[0].getVideoTracks()[0];

peerconnection.getStats(function (report) {
  console.log(report);
}, selector, logError);
```

This give out the array:

```
[RTCStatsReport, RTCStatsReport]
```

Unforunatley neither have type "ssrc".

RTCStatsReport[0] has type "googLibjingleSession"

RTCStatsReport[1] has type "googTrack"

Is my implementation incorrect or is it just not possible to access the ssrc or other information ?

Comment: same thing happened to me. I ran it again, waited a bit longer (I think), and this time I got an ssrc report

Comment: any updates on this?